# You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, sdk, linkedin-api

I need some help with the LinkedIn API. I'm getting the following error:

Uncaught Error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration.

But I already add my domain to the Javascript SDK Domains. My domain is the next one:

http://is01.inthegra-app.com.ar:8083/apex/

LinkedIn take it as a valid one but I still having the same error. The code in my page is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: API_KEY_HERE;
  onLoad: onLinkedInLoad;
  authorize: true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mandoMensaje(){
        onLinkedInLoad();
    }

   function onLinkedInLoad() {
      IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", shareContent);
    }

    function onSuccess(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }

    function onError(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    function shareContent() {
            var payload = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "x-li-format": "json",
            "comment": "Hello world...",
            "content": {
                "title": "LinkedIn API Test",
                "description": "Publish in LinkedIn from HTML and JavaScript",
                "submitted-url": "http://www.inthegra.com.ar",  
                "submitted-image-url": "http://www.inthegra.com.ar/img/logo-inthegra-blanco.png"
            },
           "visibility": {
               "code": "anyone"
           }  
      };
      IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
     .method("POST")
     .body(JSON.stringify(payload))
     .result(onSuccess)
     .error(onError);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`/apex/` is not part of the hostname/domain and port that your Javascript is being executed from.  Try removing that portion of the value in your application's configuration.